# iOS Swift how to synchronise chart drawing line, gradient and circle animations?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-graphics, core-animation

I try to synchronise animations of chart line, circle and gradient.

Here is fancy chart gif with not synchronised animations :/
[image: chart animation]

Run all animations code:

```
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(5.0)
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut))
        self?.animateLineDrawing()
        self?.animateGradient()
        self?.animateCircle()
        CATransaction.commit()
```

Line drawing animation:

```
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0.0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    lineShapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "drawLineAnimation")
    lineShapeLayer.path = curvedPath.cgPath
```

I have gradientContainer layer with gradientLayer as sublayer. I move only container mask layer over gradient Layer:

```
    let animationPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: firstPoint.x,
                                         y: chartRect.origin.y,
                                         width: 0,
                                         height: chartRect.height))
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.fromValue = animationPath.cgPath
    animation.toValue = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: firstPoint.x,
                               y: chartRect.origin.y,
                               width: chartRect.width,
                               height: chartRect.height)).cgPath
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.delegate = self
    gradientContainerLayer.mask?.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Circle animation over chart path:

```
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = viewModel.curvedPath(frame)?.cgPath
    animation.delegate = self
    circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

1. Gradient animation is not synchronised because distance over path is different from straight line, anyone has idea how to synchronise this?
2. Why circle animation timing is not equal to line animation? It look like begin and end of animations are equal so timing functions are different, why?

Comment: Well, it's very obvious that your animations have different timing functions for one thing. The magenta gradient fill is being expanded rightward linearly, but your other animations use ease-in-ease-out.

Comment: "Gradient animation is not synchronised because distance over path is different from straight line, anyone has idea how to synchronise this?" What you need to do here is use keyframe animation to specify each advance in x-position as a frame and set the time for each of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using basic and property animation switch all on `CAKeyframeAnimation`. I personally found them way simpler to tweak and more flexible in general.

Calculate position for every element to be in same `x` coordinate at same time point.
You should consider adding minimum 1 point in each point of interest (change between decreasing and increasing of `y` coordinate) so you do not cut local extremes.

Comment: Additionally I have to 
1. set animation calculationMode to ".paced" and change
2. change gradient animation keyPath to "position.x" and instead of animation values, set animation path the same as in line and circle animation.